# Group strings with similar pattern in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, algorithm

I have an array of filenames. A subset of these may have similar pattern like this (alphabet strings with a number at the end):

```
arr = %w[
  WordWord1.html
  WordWord3.html
  WordWord10.html
  WordWord11.html
  AnotherWord1.html
  AnotherWord2.html
  FileFile.html
]
```

How to identify the similar ones (they have identical substring, just their numbers differ) and move them to an array ?

```
['WordWord1.html', 'WordWord3.html', 'WordWord10.html', 'WordWord11.html']
['AnotherWord1.html', 'AnotherWord2.html']
['FileFile.html']
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
arr.group_by { |x| x[/[a-zA-Z]+/] }.values
```

Comment: `group_by` is an ActionPack addon, and isn't necessarily available to the OP

Comment: It's included in ruby 1.9, but I guess he could still have an older version.

Comment: I use rbx-head, which surprisingly does have `group_by` although it's not 1.9 compatible.

Comment: @Ian: It's available in 1.8.7 as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
filenames = ["WordWord1.html", "WordWord3.html", "WordWord10.html", "WordWord11.html", "AnotherWord1.html", "AnotherWord2.html", "FileFile.html"]
filenames.inject({}){|h,f|k = f.split(/[^a-zA-Z]/, 2).first;h[k] ||= [];h[k] << f; h}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = %w[
  WordWord1.html
  WordWord3.html
  WordWord10.html
  WordWord11.html
  AnotherWord1.html
  AnotherWord2.html
  FileFile.html
]

result = {}

arr.each do |a|
  prefix = a.match(/[A-Za-z]+/).to_s
  if result[prefix]
    result[prefix] << a
  else
    result[prefix] = [a]
  end
end

p result
```